# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kwant'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, apple-m1, apple-silicon, quantum-computing

I am trying to run kwant https://kwant-project.org/

> **Hardware Overview:** 
> Model Name: MacBook Pro 
> Model Identifier: MacBookPro18,2 
> Chip: Apple M1 Max 
> Total Number of Cores:    10 (8 performance and 2 efficiency) 
> Memory:   64 GB

I have tried:

```
pip install kwant
```

and

```
conda install -c conda-forge kwant
```

But still getting:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/m0/Documents/main_mo/repos/topocm_content/code/init_course.ipynb Cell 1 in <cell line: 11>()
      9 # 2. External package imports
     10 import holoviews
---> 11 import kwant
     12 import matplotlib
     13 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kwant'
```

Comment: The usual reason for this error is that you have multiple versions of python installed on your system.  pip installed the module for one version, but you're using a different version to run your code.

Comment: How, exactly, are you running the code?  Command-line or IDE?